# I don't get data from mysql database by running .NET Core web api controller

Tags: c#

I am new to ASP .NET Core Web api. I have a problem retrieving data in a variable located in the controller from the mysql database. I get null when before (http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast) who postman I send Get http request with the corresponding route for activation to the controller.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version is 3.1.10.

Pomelo's MySQL database provider for Entity Framework Core version 3.2.3 is in charge of communication between the Entity Framework Core and the mysql database.
Is there anyone who can give me advice on how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

This is code from controller

```
using Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NinjaServer.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private IRepositoryWrapper _repoWrapper;

    public WeatherForecastController(IRepositoryWrapper repoWrapper)
    {
        _repoWrapper = repoWrapper;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
     var someoneNinja = _repoWrapper.Ninja.FinfByCondition(x => x.Name.Equals("Matej ninja"));
        var clans = _repoWrapper.Clan.FindAll();
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

}

This is code from appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
},
"mysqlconnection": {
  "connectionString": "server=localhost;userid=root;password=mypassword;database=ninjas;"
  }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
 }
```

This is Code from Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NinjaServer.Extensions;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace NinjaServer
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
 LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the 
    container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureCors();
        services.ConfigureIISIntegration();
        services.ConfigureLoggerService();
        services.ConfigureMySqlContext(Configuration);
        services.ConfigureRepositoryWrapper();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request 
     pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
        });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
    }
    }
```

[Displays the controller during application execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCpVo.png)}

Comment: 1) what does `FinfByDefinition` make? please share the code. 2) are you 100% sure that the value you're looking for exists?

Comment: What status are you getting in the response.  The status is usually 200 when good response and 400/500 when there is an error.  Server may be expecting HTTPS (secure) instead of HTTP.

Comment: The yellow bar showing the current statement is above the line being interrogated; if you haven't executed the `var clans = _repoWrapper.Clan.FindAll();` line yet, then `clans` would naturally be null

Comment: I solved problem. It was necessary to mark the primary key with [Key] in the model on value Id using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Thank you all for the suggestions.